# Use different lock-screens on htc sensation

Tags: lock-screens, htc-sensation

Is there a way to use other lock-screens on the htc sensation then the one that is provided by htc sense **without** installing a custom rom? (rooting is fine) I would love to use the standard android lock-screens, is that possible? (I don't care if it is achieved with an app or by modifying the settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some "lock screens" like [Go Locker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock), but they are not "real" lock screens. Lock screens are just about the only part of the android OS that cannot be replaced by 3rd party applications. These other lock screens attempt to override the real lock screen. Some of them work fairly well, but I always notice some type of lag when turning on the device or unlocking the device.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found the Best List of Android lock screen apps that will help your productivity,reading ability and get live scores on your lock screens.you'll be really find it useful [Android lock screens](http://waytohunt.org/best-lock-screen-apps-for-android-that-reinvents-your-phone)